# JSF <h:outputlink> navigate to new tab

Tags: jsf

Im using JSF h:outputlink. I want to open a new tab onclick of that link.
Please suggest me the simplest way to do this.

Comment: it is a normal html link ! so using `target="_blank"` would do it... please do some research before asking such a question. for more info [outputLink](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputLink.html)

Comment: it doesnt work in h:outputlink

Answer (score 21):

Try this,

```
 <h:outputLink value="xxx.html" target="_blank">URL</h:outputLink>
```

Read [h:outputLink](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_outputlink_tag.htm) fore mo information.